# Sitecore 8: make a Rendering only visible to users with a given role

Tags: security, sitecore, sitecore8

I have a rendering which is part of a page, but I want it to be displayed only to users who have a specific Role.

I searched on the net but I could not find a solution to this - I already tried removing Read permissions for that specific Rendering, like so:

http://screencast.com/t/sAMiSGk0

but to no avail. Does anyone knows the solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use personalization in your layout details. There is a conditional rendering rule called "where the current user is a member of the [value,UserRoles,,specific] role" (in the Security group). For this condition you would set the data source (or leave it blank). In the default condition you would set "Hide Rendering"

Note: This rule does not take role inheritance into account. You would need to create a custom rule for that.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about that!

Comment: No problem, happy to help

Comment: If you need to evaluate also inherited security roles then to can take a look at my blog post that explains the process of creating such a condition.

https://exlrtglobal.atlassian.net/wiki/x/BgA3AQ